# Python Sending email using SMTP - target machine actively refused connection

Tags: python, r, email

I am trying to send email internally within work using the `smtplib` package in Python. I am running this script behind a VPN using the same proxy settings for R and Spyder.
I use the following code which was adapted from [mkyoung.com](https://mkyong.com/python/how-do-send-email-in-python-via-smtplib/)

```
import smtplib

to = 'foo@foo-corporate.com'
corp_user = 'foo@foo-corporate.com'
corp_pwd = 'password'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(local_hostname="smtp://foo-corporate.com", port = 25)
smtpserver.connect()
```

Once i try the last line `smtpserver.connect()`, I get the error message:

> [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

This would suggest that the server is not accepting SMTP requests.
However if i execute the same script in R using the `Blastula` [package](https://rstudio.github.io/blastula/) It works fine.
Can anyone suggest how I can trouble shoot this?

```
library(blastula)

create_smtp_creds_key(
  id = "email_creds",
  user = "foo@foo-corporate.com",
  host = "smtp://foo-corporate.com",
  port = 25,
  use_ssl = TRUE
)

email <-
  compose_email(
    body = md(" Hello, 
        This is a test email
        "))
  
# Sending email by SMTP using a credentials file
email %>%
  smtp_send(
    to = "foo@foo-corporate.com",
    from = "foo@foo-corporate.com",
    subject = "Testing the `smtp_send()` function",
    credentials = creds_key("email_creds")
  )
```

Comment: Port 25 is rarely an SSL port. Try connecting without ssl. I can't speak about why it worked in R but it could be due to R automatically dropping to no ssl.

Comment: Thank you @user99999 for your quick reply, I tried this but it gives me the same problem. Could the firewall be looking specifically at Python connections and blocking them (I know very little around this topic)

Comment: yep, same as @user99999, I even know ISPs that block port 25 as unsecure port and forward those requests to a dead end server. Sometimes port 465 is still used but usually 587 is the one that works

Comment: If you want further help with this I suggest that you edit your post to include the full stacktrace of the error that you get. I don't think a firewall in most cases will let a connection from one software through and block another. I don't think it would even be possible to tell the difference in the packets to even start filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @user99999 and @Ovski

Thank you for investigating this for me.
I managed to finally get it working with the below code

```
import smtplib
import ssl

to = 'foo@foo-corporate.com'
corp_user = 'foo@foo-corporate.com'
corp_pwd = 'password'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp://foo-corporate.com")
smtp_server.ehlo()
smtp_server.login(corp_user, corp_pwd)
msg_to_send = '''
hello world!
'''

smtp_server.sendmail(user,to,msg_to_send)
smtp_server.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the context is not needed at all.

This is an example using TLS. Give it a try, at least in my environment, this worked.

```
import smtplib

smtp_server = 'mail.example.com'
port = 587  # For starttls
sender_email = "from@mail.com"
receiver_email = 'to@mail.com'
password = r'password'
message = f'''\
From: from-name <from@mail.com>
To: to-name <to@mail.com>
Subject: testmail

testmail

'''
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)    
except Exception as e:
    # Print any error messages to stdout
    print(e)
finally:
    server.quit()
```

Comment: I think `smtplib` automatically creates the `context` if you don't include it.

Comment: @user99999 just testet this and you are right, it worked without the context. I just found an old script I used to send status mails from a server. I updated my answer with this as I know it is a working example. Maybe this helps